# How to test http calls in go

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have the following code:

```
// HTTPPost to post json messages to the specified url
func HTTPPost(message interface{}, url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    jsonValue, err := json.Marshal(message)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Cannot Convert to JSON: ", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    logger.Info("Calling http post with url: ", url)
    resp, err := getClient().Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue))
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Cannot post to the url: ", url, err)
        return nil, err
    }
    err = IsErrorResp(resp, url)
    return resp, err
}
```

I'd like to write the tests for this, but I am not sure how to use httptest package .

Comment: There is a lot of example in the web, have you tried something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look here:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_Server

Basically, you can create a new "mock" http server using `httptest.NewServer` function.

You can have your mock server return whatever response you need from the test, and you can also have your mock server store the request that your `HTTPPost` function made in order to assert over it.

```
func TestYourHTTPPost(t *testing.T){

    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, `response from the mock server goes here`)
        // you can also inspect the contents of r (the request) to assert over it
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    mockServerURL = ts.URL

    message := "the message you want to test"

    resp, err := HTTPPost(message, mockServerURL)

    // assert over resp and err here
}
```